# How can I work on an existing Firebase (functions) project on a different machine?

Tags: firebase, version-control, google-cloud-functions

I'm relatively new to Firebase and want to work on one Firebase Project from multiple Machines. When setting up a new Project locally via firebase CLI and attaching it to an existing Project in the cloud, there's a full project folder created in my local directory.

**Is there any chance of sort of "downloading"/updating an existing project to a second machine?**

The workaround I'd have chosen would be to manually copy the whole directory to the new environment and then `login firebase`. 
But this would, given the fact of missing source control, bring the risk of overwriting changes made on machine 1 yesterday, when `firebase deploy` from machine 2 today, wouldn't it?

Sorry for maybe not expressing myself in a decent it-guy way, but I'm far from being a full-blooded programmer.

Thanks!

Comment: the directory of your project? cant you send the project to github and then import it on another machine and do cloud functions there also

Comment: Ok, sorry, maybe I expressed it wrong. Im talking about my local file system, where a the folder I choose is filled with  "database.rules"; "firebase.json" and a folder "functions". I thought maybe there would be some kind of a github-comparable source control from firebase, where i can use the CLI to just pull the last deployed state of my project from firebase itself.

Comment: no the best thing to do, is like what I told, share the project to github and then import it in another machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to manage your source code yourself, typically using a source control mechanism such as git or svn.  Firebase does not provide a source control system for the code and configuration that you deploy to Cloud Functions.